# how to set custom param in BasicHttpParams

Tags: java, exception, apache-httpclient-4.x

the following is my piese of code where i set custome parameters

```
CreateRequisitionRO[] request = new CreateRequisitionRO[1];
boolean validateOnly = true;
HttpPost postURI = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/api/trade/createrequisition");

            // Setup the request parameters
            BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            params.setParameter("CreateRequisitionRO", request.toString());
            params.setParameter("validateOnly", "true");
            postURI.setParams(params);
            HttpResponse responseURL = client.execute(postURI);
```

in the above `CreateRequisitionRO` user defined class and i have Boolean type too.

i am not able to set them in to `params.setParameter` since it accepts only string. how to set my class as a parameter because the method i call is defined with these custom and boolean type.

Please help to resolve this.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BasicHttpParams#setBooleanParameter` which exists in super class `AbstractHttpParams`,

```
params.setBooleanParameter("validateOnly", true);
```

and `BasicHttpParams#setParameter(String name, Object value)` which accept Object as a value you can also pass your custom `CreateRequisitionRO` array request.

> params.setParameter("CreateRequisitionRO", request);

Comment: Thanks for the post, it helped. i now get this ` Resolving exception from handler [public void com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI.createRequisition(com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO[],boolean)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported`

Comment: `application/octet-stream` is not supported, you may try  `application/ogg`

Comment: how to set content type ??

Comment: `HttpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/ogg");`

Comment: Great Help, Much appreciated for spending your valuable time for me. :). Marked as answer with upvote